# HTML code inside php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

this may be a beginner question but i am struggling a lot with it
below is my php code

```
echo '
            var comment_value = $('#commentbox').val();
            console.log(comment_value);
                getcomment: "comment_value" } ,

  ';
```

here the problem is that php consider # as comment out statement because of which i can't populate my html file with this jquery command. Thank you

Comment: That would actually be javascript inside PHP, and there's a quote mismatch as well? Did you echo some script tags to go with that ?

Comment: no, the problem is that PHP is terminating the string at the ' before that # sign. Try echoing with " double quotes. Or better yet, break out of PHP to write things like js and html

Comment: The color coding in your post shows you the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You're quote inside your javascript is breaking out of the echo quotes. You need to do something like:

```
echo 'var comment_value = $("#commentbox").val();';
```

Alternatively you could escape the quote:

```
echo 'var comment_value = $(\'#commentbox\').val();';
```

However, it's probably best to just break out of PHP

```
<?php
   // Some php code
?>

<script>var comment_value = $("#commentbox").val();</script>

<?php 
    // Some more code
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Or this way:

```
echo '
        var comment_value = $("#commentbox").val();
        console.log(comment_value);
        getcomment: "comment_value" } ,

      ';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '
  var comment_value = $(\'#commentbox\').val();
  console.log(comment_value);
  getcomment: "comment_value" } ,
';
```